# loadFromJSON dosen't work with clipto

Tags: html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

loadFromJSON dosen't work with clipto parameter even I tried on http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink which given as demo.

Object shown as rounded on canvas as well but when I export as JSON file fabricJS exports incorrect stuffs so I can't load the JSON file again.

The exported JSON:

```
{"objects":[{"type":"rect","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":241,"top":253,"width":50,"height":50,"fill":"#06980e","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":5.59,"scaleY":5.59,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":0.8,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":"function (ctx) {\n ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);\n }","backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","transformMatrix":null,"skewX":0,"skewY":0,"rx":0,"ry":0}],"background":""}
```

How can I solve this? Probably Issue about this part of code.

```
    $scope.clip = function() {
      var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
      if (!obj) return;

      if (obj.clipTo) {
          obj.clipTo = null;
      }
      else {
          var radius = obj.width < obj.height ? (obj.width / 2) : (obj.height / 2);
          obj.clipTo = function (ctx) {
              ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
          };
      }
      canvas.renderAll();
  };
```

Comment: are you talking about the `/n` that is coming into the `json` ?

Comment: no, I mean 
ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true)
radius have to be a numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

I just able to solve this issue:

```
object.cLeft = -(eWidth / 2) + left;
object.cTop = -(eHeight / 2) + top;
object.cWidth = parseInt(width * eScaleX);
object.cHeight = parseInt(eScaleY * height);

object.clipTo = function (ctx) {
  ctx.rect(this.cLeft, this.cTop, this.cWidth, this.cHeight);
}
```

When storing canvas in JSON Format:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(canvas.toObject(['cLeft','cTop','cWidth','cHeight']));
```

Working example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/Shahbaz/k8ewrvsc/3/

Comment: This is a good solution. However, this clips the object to integers not variables which results in a somehow non-flexible clip.

Meaning that by dragging the object you still see a fixed clipped area.
Whereas if we clip to variables, by dragging the object, you'll see that the clipped area varies (withing the boundaries of the object we are clipping to)